# Overlapping Lines on Vector

Tags: postgis

Using PostGIS my objective is to find overlapping lines sitting on a vector.

[image: example lines]

While this query works as expected.

```
SELECT ST_Covers(
    ST_GeomFromText('LineString (0 0 , 2 2)'),
    ST_GeomFromText('LineString (0 0 , 1 1)')
);

st_covers
-----------
 t
(1 row)
```

The following query does not. The lines are sourced from the same original linestring (they are the output of a `ST_Split` procedure). I guess it is due to the floating points. Are there any easy tricks I could apply here to make certain `ST_Covers` returns true? I tried `ST_SnapToGrid` but so far without any luck.

```
SELECT ST_Covers(
    ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-76.4631041 38.9533412, -76.45349643519081 38.96398666895439)'),
    ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-76.4631041 38.9533412, -76.45514403057082 38.962161103032216)')
);

st_covers
-----------
 f
(1 row)
```

Comment: Have you tried with a buffer?

Comment: I did actually try with a buffer which didn't turn out to work either. However I am seeing some luck with `ST_Snap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`ST_Snap`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Snap.html) *"snaps the vertices and segments of a geometry to another Geometry's vertices"* which is what is required in this case; the following example contains 2 overlapping linestrings and 2 others which do not overlap.

```
WITH lines AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_GeomFromText(
    'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(
        LINESTRING(-76.4631041 38.9533412, -76.45514403057082 38.962161103032216),
        LINESTRING(-76.4631041 38.9533412, -76.45349643519081 38.96398666895439),
        LINESTRING(-76.45349643519081 38.96398666895439,-76.4525346 38.9650524),
        LINESTRING(-76.45514403057082 38.962161103032216,-76.45349643519081 38.96398666895439)
    )'
))).geom AS geom)
SELECT ST_Covers(a.geom, ST_Snap(b.geom, a.geom, 0.01))
FROM lines a, lines b;
```